# Optparse-applicative: consecutive parsing (ReadM)

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative, optparse-applicative

I have a basic command `add` that takes 2 kind of arguments: a word or a tag. A tag is just a word starting by `+`. A word is just a `String`. It can contain at least one argument (I use `some` for this).

```hs
data Arg = Add AddOpts

data AddOpts = AddOpts
  { desc :: String,
    tags :: [String]
  }
  deriving (Show)

addCommand :: Mod CommandFields Arg
addCommand = command "add" (info parser infoMod)
  where
    infoMod = progDesc "Add a new task"
    parser = Add <$> parseDescAndTags <$> partition isTag <$> some (argument str (metavar "DESC"))
    parseDescAndTags (_, []) = FAIL HERE
    parseDescAndTags (tags, desc) = AddOpts (unwords desc) (map tail tags)
```

I want to add another rule: the `add` command should receive at least one word (but 0 or more tags). For this, I need to check after the first parsing the word list. If it's empty, I would like to fail as if the `add` commands received no argument, but I can't figure out how to do.

Answer (score 1):

`parseDescAndTags` is currently a pure function, so there’s no way for it to cause parsing to fail. Just to get this out of the way, I should also note that in this code:

```
Add <$> parseDescAndTags <$> partition isTag <$> some (argument str (metavar "DESC"))
```

The operator `<$>` is declared `infixl 4`, so it’s left-associative, and your expression is therefore equivalent to:

```
((Add <$> parseDescAndTags) <$> partition isTag) <$> some (argument str (metavar "DESC"))
```

You happen to be using `<$>` in the “function reader” functor, `(->) a`, which is equivalent to composition `(.)`:

```
Add . parseDescAndTags . partition isTag <$> some (argument str (metavar "DESC"))
```

If you want to use `ReadM`, you need to use functions such as [`eitherReader`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.15.1.0/docs/Options-Applicative.html#v:eitherReader) to construct a `ReadM` action. But the problem is that you would need to use it as the first argument to `argument` instead of the `str` reader, and that’s the wrong place for it, since `some` is on the *outside* and you want to fail parsing based on the accumulated results of the *whole* option.

Unfortunately that kind of context-sensitive parsing is not what `optparse-applicative` is designed for; it doesn’t offer a `Monad` instance for parsers.

Currently, your parser allows tags and descriptions to be *interleaved*, like this (supposing `isTag = (== ".") . take 1` for illustration):

```
add some .tag1 description .tag2 text
```

Producing `"some description text"` for the description and `[".tag1", ".tag2"]` as the tags. Is that what you want, or can you use a simpler format instead, like requiring all tags at the end?

```
add some description text .tag1 .tag2
```

If so, the result is simple: parse at least one non-tag with `some`, then any number of tags with `many`:

```
addCommand :: Mod CommandFields Arg
addCommand = command "add" (info parser infoMod)
  where
    infoMod = progDesc "Add a new task"
    parser = Add <$> addOpts
    addOpts = AddOpts
      <$> (unwords <$> some (argument nonTag (metavar "DESC")))
      <*> many (argument tag (metavar "TAG"))

    nonTag = eitherReader
      $ \ str -> if isTag str
        then Left ("unexpected tag: '" <> str <> "'")
        else Right str

    tag = eitherReader
      $ \ str -> if isTag str
        then Right $ drop 1 str
        else Left ("not a tag: '" <> str <> "'")
```

As an alternative, you can *parse* command-line options with `optparse-applicative`, but do any more complex *validation* on your options records after running the parser. Then if you want to print the help text manually, you can use:

```
printHelp :: ParserPrefs -> ParserInfo a -> IO a
printHelp parserPrefs parserInfo = handleParseResult $ Failure
  $ parserFailure parserPrefs parserInfo ShowHelpText mempty
```

Comment: Thank you for the simplification. I'm still new to Haskell, those things don't come easily to my mind yet. What I try to do is to have words and tags mixed, that's why I went for a `parseDescAndTags`. I like your second approach. I will still search a bit more to see if I can't find a better alternative. I would like to print the same output as if the arg was totally missing.

Comment: I was thinking about throwing an error, and showing the help as you mentioned on catch. Is it considered a good practice in Haskell?

Comment: @soywod: If you *expect* an error to happen, you should prefer value-level error handling with e.g. `Maybe`, `Either`, or `Validation`. Here you could parse to an “unvalidated arguments” `newtype` wrapper for `Arg`, then have a function `validate :: UnvalidatedArg -> Either String Arg` to check the invariants that can’t go in the parser directly. Then print the help and the error message if its result is `Left message`. Exceptions (`throw`, `throwIO`) are better for *unexpected* or *unrecoverable* errors; also, you can only catch exceptions in `IO`, so you can’t use them in normal pure code.