# Perform checks that include multiple options

Tags: haskell, applicative, optionparser, optparse-applicative

I have

```
type Month = Int

parseMonths :: OP.Parser (Month, Month)
parseMonths =
    liftA2 (,)
        (OP.option
            (OP.eitherReader $
             parseNumber "month" (\n -> 1<=n && n<=12) "month")
            (OP.metavar "MONTH" <>
             OP.long "from-month" <>
             OP.value 1))
        (OP.option
            (OP.eitherReader $
             parseNumber "month" (\n -> 1<=n && n<=12) "month")
            (OP.metavar "MONTH" <>
             OP.long "to-month" <>
             OP.value 12))
```

I want to add a check, that the first month is not after the second month. Obviously I cannot do that in `OP.ReadM`. Can I perform the check in `OP.Parser`? Or do I have to perform the check after parsing with `parserFailure` like here:
[Optparse-applicative: consecutive parsing (ReadM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63177527/optparse-applicative-consecutive-parsing-readm)
?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I perform the check in `OP.Parser`?

No.

`Parser` is only an `Applicative` and not a `Monad` (hence the package name, `optparse-applicative`). This is a [typical feature of parser functors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50174323/why-would-validation-break-the-monad-laws) - because the `Applicative` instance collects as many errors as possible, there is no possible lawful `Monad` instance.

Without being a `Monad`, it's impossible to write `Parser`s that depend on the result of other `Parser`s - since that's the defining feature of monads.

---

However, `optparse-applicative` does offer an escape hatch, if you really need one: use [`ParserM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.16.1.0/docs/Options-Applicative-Types.html#t:ParserM).

`ParserM` is basically an alternative to `Parser` which is a `Monad` - at the cost of dropping error messages some of the time. You can write a monadic parser using `ParserM`, and then use `runParserM` to turn it back into a regular `Parser`.

Comment: `OP.Parser` being `Applicative` and not `Monad` only means that you cannot define `bind` or `join` of `Monad` class. However, in principle there could be a custom function like `checkMulti :: (a -> Maybe String) -> OP.Parser a -> OP.Parser a` that provides my wanted functionality.